# minimum and maximum of moving window, better implementation?

Tags: scala, queue, max, min

I am trying to find a min-max of a moving window by using queues. I was able to create a solution but this feels very slow.

Here is my solution:

```
def min_max(value:T, windowSize: Int):(T,T) = {
  val queue = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[A]()   //I added the creation of this queue here for you to see
  if(queue.size == windowSize) queue.dequeue
  queue.enqueue(value)    
  var min = queue.head
  var max = queue.head
  for(i <- queue) {
    if(i<min) min = i
    if(i>max) max = i
  }
  (min, max)                 // returns the min and max in a tuple
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your queue is constructed and populated, and how large it is. In short, you can make scanning for min/max faster, but it'll make adding elements to the queue slower, or incur some upfront cost.

What you are doing is linear, which is about as good as you can do with a linear data struct, but you could write it in a more idiomatic manner (and also I am not sure what's the deal with `dequeue` in the beginning, and what you expect to happen when the queue size is less or larger than the parameter):

```
 queue
  .take(windowSize)
  .foldLeft(Option.empty[A] -> Option.empty[A]) { 
     case ((None, None), x) => Some(x) -> Some(x)
     case ((x, y), z) => x.map(x min z) -> y.map(y max z)
  }
```

This also assumes that there is no race (nobody is adding data to the queue while you are traversing it). All this stuff would be a lot easier to reason about if you adopted the functional approach of not using mutable structures unless you absolutely have to.